# line integral over differential explained in loose terms

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential, line-integrals

today I learned about exact and inexact differentials. There you often integrate the differential $dF(x,y)$ along a certain path $\gamma_1$ (here in 2D) like this
$$
\int_{\gamma_1} dF
$$
my question is now what is the difference between this and
$$
\int_{\gamma_1}F(x,y)ds=\int_{a}^{b}F(\gamma_1(t))|\gamma_1'(t)|dt
$$
where $\gamma_1: [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$
(assuming that the differential is in 2D and exact. Otherwise there couldn't be an $F$ to integrate over obviously)
The second is a line integral of $F$. So it a sum over the values $F$ has along that path. But how can the first integral be explained in loose terms? Is it just the sum of the values of the derivative along the path?

Comment: I've never seen an integral of the second type.

Comment: @Randall I edited it. The line integral should be written correctly now

Comment: The first integral is the line integral of the one-form $dF=\partial_xF\,dx+\partial_yF\,dy$ over the curve $\gamma_1\,,$ or equivalently, the line integral of the gradient of $F$ over that curve. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_vector_field). It can be written as $$\int_a^b \nabla F(\gamma_1(t))\cdot \gamma'_1(t)\,dt\,.$$